# Matrices where $A^2 = A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a feeling that the only invertible matrix - $A$ . that when it squared $A^2$ is still $A$ , is the Identity matrix.
Am I right?  and if so , could anybody show me the proof?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes: multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: This aint exactly rocket science here :)

Comment: @Zarrax: We're on a mathematics website, so I expect it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible, multiplying $A^2=A$ by $A^{-1}$ you get $A=I$